# Why flutter bloc says, "Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close." While I ma passing the bloc from prvious screen?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have created a bloc on 1 bloc on home page.

That is passed to drawer then profile page and profile update page.

During the whole flow I just close the drawer ad navigate to next page to when users close back. Hhe does have to see already open drawer but.

```
Scaffold.of(context).closeEndDrawer();
```

But in profile update page.

```
emit(AppBaseState.busy());
```

Isn't working due to following error:

```
Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close.
```

I am expectiing to udate profile normally.

Answer (score 0):

You might check [the doc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocprovider):

> In some cases, BlocProvider can be used to provide an existing bloc to a new portion of the widget tree. ***This will be most commonly used when an existing bloc needs to be made available to a new route.*** **In this case, BlocProvider will not automatically close the bloc since it did not create it**.

```
BlocProvider.value(
  value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),
  child: ScreenA(),
);
```

> then from either ChildA, or ScreenA we can retrieve BlocA with:

```
// with extensions
context.read<BlocA>();

// without extensions
BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context)
```